# Jakarta @Pattern regex failing when specifiying max length

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jakarta-validation

Working:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*\\d)(.{8,})$")
private String str;
```

Never matches (no matter if str is valid or not):

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*\\d)(.{8,30})$")
private String str;
```

The only difference in the second pattern is the max length (30) beeing specified.

The second regex works though if I use `String.matches()`:

```
String regex = "^(?=.*\\d)(.{8,30})$";
String validString= "12345678"; // 8 chars
assertTrue(validString.matches(regex));

String invalidString = "123456789012345678901234567890A"; // 31 chars
assertFalse(invalidString.matches(regex));
```

I also successfully tried the second regex on https://regex101.com/ ...

Anyone got an idea how I could change the second regex for it to work with the `@Pattern` annotation?

I'm using spring-boot 3.2.3, java 17 and gradle 7.5.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC, we should use `[` and `]` for a fixed number of repettions. Can you try `^(?=.*\\d)(.[8,30])$`?

Comment: No working I'm afraid. Tried it with @Pattern and with online regex checker as well (https://regex101.com/). Is ```[]``` really the syntax for length? I only know it for specifying range like ```[A-Z]```

Comment: nope, it isn't. Just double-checked,`{` and `}` were correct all along.

Comment: `@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*\\d)(.{8,30})$")` does work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused by hibernate validation during persistence time. I was encrypting the string just before saving it, that's why the regex did not work during persistence action anymore and I got confusing results.

Solution:
add

```
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

to properties. This will prevent validation during db actions.
See hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent